# Passing property name to aggregate

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have this method which needs to be called for different properties (returning `IEnumerable<string>`) like `MyList` for each child in `Children`

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetMyListAggregatedValues()
    {
        var aggregatedValues = new List<string>();
        return Children.Aggregate(aggregatedValues , (current, child) => current.Union(child.MyList).ToList());
    }
```

One way to solve this is to call it for each of those properties against Children.

So my questions is, is there a way to somehow avoid this repetitive code and dynamically pass property name (without using reflection, which would be an overkill I think).

So, statically, these calls will be made like

```
GetMyListAggregatedValues();
GetAnotherListAggregatedValues();
```

And what I am after (if possible)

```
GetAggregatedValues(_SOMETHING_.MyList);
```

Comment: Have you looked into using dynamic linq? It allows you to pass in strings as linq expressions instead of lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the properties in question implement `IEnumerable<string>` then it's pretty easy. Just package the "given a child, access one of its properties" logic into a lambda:

```
public IEnumerable<string> 
GetAggregatedValues(Func<Child, IEnumerable<string>> selector)
{
    var aggregatedValues = new List<string>();
    return Children.Aggregate(
        aggregatedValues , 
        (current, child) => current.Union(selector(child)).ToList()
    );
}
```

and call it with

```
GetAggregatedValues(c => c.MyList);
```

You can even generalize this further by making `string` a type argument wherever it appears in the above code, then the same construct would also work for `IEnumerable<int>` etc.

Comment: That's a great answer, just one thing which I am unsure, what would be the `Child` in `Func<Child, IEnumerable<string>> selector`?